# How to prevent Android from closing web-application when backbutton is pressed?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, back-button

I am developing a HTML5 web-application and compiling it with Cordova (phonegap) 1.7.

I want to override the Android backbutton so that I can call window.history.back() instead of closing the application (default Android). How can I prevent Android from killing the defaultactivity on back button pressed?

I get the "Back button pressed!!!!" in logcat, so the method is fired before the application is closed.

This is what I have so far:

```
        // Wait for Cordova to load
        //
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // Cordova is ready
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {

            document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e) {

                console.log("Back button pressed!!!!");                 
                window.history.back();


            }, false);

        }
```

EDIT: I am willing to accept an answer explaining a way to simulate the window.history.back() directly from the DefaultActivity.java android class if that is possible!

Comment: That code should work. Where did you get the 1.7 version of PG as it is not released yet. Are you building off of github?

Comment: @SimonMacDonald 1.7rc1 released on download.phonegap.com last Thursday. See http://phonegap.com/2012/04/26/1-7-0rc1-released/

Comment: The code does sadly not work :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved my own question by adding the code below to the `DefaultActivity.java` file to prevent the default android behavior, and keeping the JavaScript code as stated in the question:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   return;
}
```

I hope this helps someone in the future with the same problem!

Comment: I am using phonegap 1.7 and this seems to be the only approach that works. However, I would prefer a non-native solution so that it works on things like phonegap build. Help much appreciated.

Comment: I also tried the same code ... but now it neither close the app nor return back .... back button is disabled .... can you suggest me to fix this so that i can get back to last visited page

Answer (score 2):

I took this approach. I hooked the backbutton event as you have shown. I look to see if this is the first page or not and then ask the user if they want to exit the program or not.  This depends on what you want your program to do depending on its state.  I did not add the override as you have shown; I didnot seem to need it.

```
if ($.mobile.activePage.attr('id') === 'firstpage') {
    // Prompt to confirm the exit
} else {
  window.history.back();
}
```

If they want to exit you can call:

```
navigator.app.exitApp();
```

to close your program.

I imagine you still want to allow the user to exit your app. I don't tend to use apps that
do not allow an exit of some kind.

Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

Never had to do that but, have you tried to `return true` ?

Like in the Java SDK, if you return `True`, the system will assume you have correctly catched the event and will no longer pass it to other event listeners.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried. But it sadly did not work. I've also just printing to console, and not doing back(), but it still exits. Weird!