# "[undefined] is not a function" when handling backbutton event in PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, back-button

I am trying to work with the back button with help from the [PhoneGap Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#backbutton) and [Override Android Backbutton behavior only works on the first page with PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631933/override-android-backbutton-behavior-only-works-on-the-first-page-with-phonegap).

My code:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
  function onDeviceReady() {
    alert("df");
        console.log("PhoneGap Ready!");
         document.addEventListener("backbutton", handleBackButton, false);
    }

    function handleBackButton() {
        console.log("Back Button Pressed!");
        alert("df");

    }
</script>
```

But I get this error:

> 05-21 16:00:03.248: E/Web Console(1615): TypeError: Result of expression 'PhoneGap.fireDocumentEvent' [undefined] is not a function. at undefined:1

Comment: Not sure if it's the same problem, but I solved my backbutton handling issues overriding onBackPressed in the activity class:

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   return;
}

Comment: i tried this also by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382634/how-to-prevent-android-from-closing-web-application-when-backbutton-is-pressed link.no sound

Comment: Ok, this answer is a bit silly, but just for make it sure, have you linked the correct cordova-x.js? I mean, you didn't attach the js for iOS, Blackberry, etc., did you?

Comment: ok i got i change the js file thank you]

Comment: Did it work? In that case I'll post an answer

Comment: ya work,Suppose i want to navigate the previous page in back button wat can i do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that you are linking the correct phonegap-x.js for the platform, the javascript code is different for android, iOS, etc.

When the back button is pressed in Android, the event 'backbutton' is fired, so if you want to go back in the navigation history, what you should do is attaching the following handler to it:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    navigator.app.backHistory();
}, true);
```

Comment: @ davidThank you  i tried  this code but it doesnt goes to the previous page.

Comment: Try replacing 'navigator.app.backHistory()' with 'window.history.back()'. I would really encourage you to upgrade your phonegap version, though

Comment: function onDeviceReady() {
   
        console.log("PhoneGap Ready!");
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("sd");
    window.history.back();
}, false);
    }

Comment: It should be, which device are you developing for?

Comment: Sorry am checking in emulaotr 2.2

Comment: which version of phonegap are you using?

Comment: navigator.app.backHistory() should work as long as you test in a real device or android emulator. Ensure that the event gets fired and the handler is called