# Cordova, PhoneGap 1.7 Android back button not firing

Tags: android, cordova, back-button

I am using Cordova 1.7 on Android, and it seems to be working (i.e: I can select an image from the gallery for example) but I can't get the back button event to fire. When pressing the back button the app automatically closes. My build target is Android 2.2.

I put this in the `onReady` method, exactly as the stated in the API:

```
document.removeEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382634/how-to-prevent-android-from-closing-web-application-when-backbutton-is-pressed

Answer (score 3):

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton" , onBackKeyDown, false);     

function  onBackKeyDown(){    
   // Do something here    
   alert('back button was pushed');
```

}

addeventlistener, not remove event

Comment: Yes, sorry. this is what I did. AddEventListener... sorry I must have typed it fast without noticing. 
Everything used to work when I was using phonegap 1.4.1. I fear it is something to do with that. I must have missed something in the transition to cordova 1.7, although I did go over the instructions carefully. The weird thing, like I mentioned earlier, is that other Phonegap methods function as expected.
Thanks for your help,
Shachar