# Back Button not working in phonegap android

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a phonegap app where i am using JQM for designing my pages.

The Issue i am facing is that Back Button generated by JQM is not working on android platforms on *some cases*. it works fine on IOS though

**EDIT:**
It works on Browsers too. So i suspect there may be some issue while using cordova.

I tried following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774608/cordova-phonegap-1-7-android-back-button-not-firing) and upgraded to cordova 1.8 from 1.7, but this dint solve my problem.

*Cases* where back button is not working

I have few JQM files that are called from the index page. Back button is not operational on these files. but inside those files there are [JQM pages](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/docs/pages/docs-pages.html) where Back Button does works

Back button is a standard JQM back button

```
<a data-role="button" data-rel="back">Back</Back>
```

I am stuck on this since long time.

Can anyone provide some directions?

**EDIT:**

Just to eliminate any confusion. BackButton event listener([Reference](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#backbutton) and suggested in the comments) does gets called. But this is device's back button(the physical button). My issues are with JQM's back button i.e back button with data-rel="back"

Comment: Why dont you use phonegap to handle the backbutton like this `document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackClickEvent, false);`

Comment: i looked at your answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945643/correct-way-of-using-jquery-mobile-phonegap-together .. but its working fine on IOS platform. what could be wrong.

Comment: Are you talking about `<a data-role="button" data-rel="back">Back</Back>` is working on iOS but not on Android… Or are you talking about my sample?

Comment: i am saying that former is not working <a data-role="button" data-rel="back">Back</Back>

Comment: See either you make use of Phonegap's backbutton listener or if you want to know whats wrong with your `<a data-role="button" data-rel="back">Back</Back>` then please post some code so that we can look on it and tell what are you doing wrong...

Comment: its not listening to phonegaps's backbutton. i tried alerting.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14455/discussion-between-coder-slay-and-mashit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your code i cant help you with your JQM backbutton issue.. Although i can propose a new solution.

You can register a backbutton listener like this

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton",onBackClickEvent,false);
```

then in the onBackClickEvent you can use it like this

```
function onBackClickEvent {

var currentPageId = $.mobile.activePage.attr('id');

  if(currentpageId == 'home') {
    $.mobile.changePage("#page2",{ transition : "slide"});
  } else {...}
}
```

Like this you can control the flow of your application. Hope this will help...

Comment: i have already tried this. "backbutton" eventListener is only catching device's back button and not the Back button generated by JQM. using device's back button app runs fine. ok i will update the code

Comment: Come on yaar... this wont automatically do it... You need to call a function onclick of you back button....

Comment: I told you i gave you an alternative... If you apply it then it will work on all platforms.....

Comment: it doesnot work when i open a page using data-rel = "external". can u check with demo code?

Comment: can you please check for  data-rel = "external". Thnx